# How to pushdpown order by clause in presto elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, presto, presto-jdbc, starburst

I am running a SQL query in starburst-presto. It's connected to elasticsearch using the relevant connector.

The SQL has an "order by" clause. This clause is not pushing down to elasticsearch. Basically, I want to sort the data in elasticsearch based on a specific field and return the result. The query with "order by" is taking a lot of time using presto. Is it possible to manage is somehow to get an optimal performance?

SQL: `select e.employee_id from elasticsearch.es."employee:id:""2390571"" && (doj_timestamp:(>=15965454 && <=15972366)) sort=employee_id:desc" e offset 0 limit 5;`

The above query is returning random results.

Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has both ORDER BY and LIMIT, so in Presto it is called a Top N query.
Presto currently does not provide Top N pushdown, but this feature is in the works.

- Umbrella issue for connector pushdown: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/18
- A draft PR for Top N pushdown (engine & SPI support): https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/4784

Please file an issue for Elasticsearch connector TopN pushdown. We will implement it anyway, but direct user feedback helps understand issue priorities.

You can learn more on the `#pushdown` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Comment: Thanks @Piotr for the information. I was struggling to get this in website, finally I downloaded the presto github code and found the same. I have added myself in the channel and logged my issue there. Do you want me to file the issue anywhere else?

Comment: For posterity, the issue link - https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/4803